# How to create Payment gateway using stripe in android pay?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, android-pay

i am able to get the token using Build your own credit card form to create and validate card detail and get token using following code,

```
 Card card=new Card(cardno,expmon,expyer,cvv);

        card.validateNumber();

        card.validateCVC();


        new Stripe().createToken(card,PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
                new TokenCallback() {
                    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                        // Send token to your own web service


                    }
                    public void onError(Exception error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
```

but i don't know how to Use Android Pay to access your customer’s stored card information in the android pay using stripe, i am using following code but i am not getting token

```
Class Androidpay  extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // You will need to use your live API key even while testing
    public static final String PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_test_zbtcr8iFQrLNU3zu1";

    // Unique identifiers for asynchronous requests:
    private static final int LOAD_MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int LOAD_FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private SupportWalletFragment walletFragment;

    public static final int mEnvironment = WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.androidpay);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Wallet.API, new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                        .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                        .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
                        .build())
                .build();


        Wallet.Payments.isReadyToPay(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<BooleanResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull BooleanResult booleanResult) {
                        if (booleanResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            if (booleanResult.getValue()) {
                                showAndroidPay();
                            } else {
                                // Hide Android Pay buttons, show a message that Android Pay
                                // cannot be used yet, and display a traditional checkout button
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Error making isReadyToPay call
                          //  Log.e(TAG, "isReadyToPay:" + booleanResult.getStatus());
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    public void showAndroidPay()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        walletFragment =
                (SupportWalletFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.wallet_fragment);

        MaskedWalletRequest maskedWalletRequest = MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()

                // Request credit card tokenization with Stripe by specifying tokenization parameters:
                .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
                        .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.PAYMENT_GATEWAY)
                        .addParameter("gateway", "stripe")
                        .addParameter("stripe:publishableKey", PUBLISHABLE_KEY)
                        .addParameter("stripe:version", com.stripe.Stripe.VERSION)
                        .build())

                // You want the shipping address:
                .setShippingAddressRequired(true)

                // Price set as a decimal:
                .setEstimatedTotalPrice("20.00")
                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                .build();

        // Set the parameters:
        WalletFragmentInitParams initParams = WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
                .setMaskedWalletRequest(maskedWalletRequest)
                .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(LOAD_MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE)
                .build();

        // Initialize the fragment:
        walletFragment.initialize(initParams);

    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == LOAD_MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE) { // Unique, identifying constant
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                MaskedWallet maskedWallet = data.getParcelableExtra(WalletConstants.EXTRA_MASKED_WALLET);
                FullWalletRequest fullWalletRequest = FullWalletRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
                                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                                .setTotalPrice("20.00")
                                .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder() // Identify item being purchased
                                        .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                                        .setQuantity("1")
                                        .setDescription("Premium Llama Food")
                                        .setTotalPrice("20.00")
                                        .setUnitPrice("20.00")
                                        .build())
                                .build())
                        .setGoogleTransactionId(maskedWallet.getGoogleTransactionId())
                        .build();
                Wallet.Payments.loadFullWallet(googleApiClient, fullWalletRequest, LOAD_FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == LOAD_FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                FullWallet fullWallet = data.getParcelableExtra(WalletConstants.EXTRA_FULL_WALLET);
                String tokenJSON = fullWallet.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken();

                //A token will only be returned in production mode,
                //i.e. WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION
                if (mEnvironment == WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
                {
                    com.stripe.model.Token token = com.stripe.model.Token.GSON.fromJson(
                            tokenJSON, com.stripe.model.Token.class);

                    // TODO: send token to your server


                    Toast.makeText(Androidpay.this,"ready to send token"+token.getId()+token.getAmount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}
}
```

Comment: Did you get solution ? i am using same code but i got the control in following condition
  // Hide Android Pay buttons, show a message that Android Pay
                                // cannot be used yet, and display a traditional checkout button

Answer (score 0):

token is in your FullWallet object. `fullWallet.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken()`. Sent the token to Stripe server.

Answer (score 0):

With Debug APK and Environment set to TEST retrieve the Full Wallet request in the onActivityResult callback to get the test token.

```
// Get payment method token  
PaymentMethodToken token = fullWallet.getPaymentMethodToken();

// Get the JSON of the token object as a String  
String tokenJSON = token.getToken();
```